# jquerytools tooltip on ajax issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-tools

Ok im doing an ajax call every 15 seconds, this the first time "disable" the tooltip when ajax call was made, i fix this running a function an calling again the function that starts tooltip.

The problem is.. If there is one tooltip "open" when the ajax call is made, this and only this tooltip of this item is destroyed forever, the rest is working fine. until again you are on a open tooltip when the ajax run.

How can i fix this..

here is my code

```
  function notifications() {
        $.ajax(
                {
                    type: "POST",
                    //data: dataparam,
                    url: "<?php echo $notifurl;?>",
                    success: function(msg)
                        {
                            if(msg !="")
                            {
                                $("#ajaxnotif").empty().html(msg);
                                $('.tooltip').remove();
                                 ttp();
                                //$("#suggestDiv").show();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $("#ajaxnotif").empty().html(msg); 
                                $('.tooltip').remove();
                                ttp();
                                //$("#suggestDiv").hide();
                            }
                        }
                });
        }


$(document).ready(notifications);
window.setInterval(function(){
  notifications();
}, 15000);

var $tooltip = null;
    var $tooltip2 = null;
var $tooltip3 = null;
    function ttp() {

    $tooltip = $('.marcleidnot[title]').tooltip({
    delay:0,
    slideInSpeed: 300,
    slideOutSpeed: 200,
    bounce: false,
    /*bounce: false*/
    relative: false, // <-- Adding this should sort you out
    slideOffset: 5,
   /* effect: 'slide',
    direction: 'down',
    slideInSpeed: 300,
    slideOutSpeed: 200,*/
    position: 'top center'
});


$tooltip2 = $('.fav[title]').tooltip({  
    delay:100,
    slideInSpeed: 300,
    slideOutSpeed: 300,
    /*bounce: false,*/
    relative: false, // <-- Adding this should sort you out
   effect: 'slide',
    direction: 'down',
    /*slideInSpeed: 300,
    slideOutSpeed: 200,*/
    position: 'top center',
    offset: [10, -2]
});

 $tooltip3 = $('.nofav[title]').tooltip({
    delay:100,
    slideInSpeed: 300,
    slideOutSpeed: 300,
    /*bounce: true,*/
    relative: false, // <-- Adding this should sort you out
    effect: 'slide',
    direction: 'down',
    /*slideInSpeed: 300,
    slideOutSpeed: 200,*/
    position: 'top center',
    offset: [10, -2]
});

    }


$('body').click(function() {
  $('.tooltip').remove();//remove the tool tip element
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to user3352495, i figure out what the problem was, then i figure out this

```
$tooltip = $('.marcleidnot[title]').tooltip("destroy");
$tooltip2 = $('.fav[title]').tooltip("destroy");
$tooltip3 = $('.nofav[title]').tooltip("destroy");
```

Wich is working fine until now

ACtually i found out i just need to delete this!

just restarting the function doing

ttp(); in the ajax solve this :D

Answer (score 1):

I think you aren't properly using the tooltip api. So instead of

```
$('.tooltip').remove();
```

do

```
$tooltip.tooltip("destroy");
$tooltip2.tooltip("destroy");
$tooltip3.tooltip("destroy");
```

Comment: nope maybe is not jquerytools format? .. i get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'tooltip' of null "

Comment: Try putting the ajax call after all the tooltips have been initialized.

Comment: i just tried that i thought that was the problem also but even like that i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the tooltip in Jquery Tools doesn't create the `.tooptip` elements by default but only creates them when the tooltips appear for the first time. So in your case, when `$tooltip` appears there's only one `.tooltip` element associating with it, the other 2 haven't appeared yet.

To comprehensively remove all tooltips, you can use [this plugin](https://gist.github.com/gid79/854708). It removes the `.tooltip` element if it's already there or unbinds the mouse events if it's not. After adding the plugin you can simply call `$tooltip.tooltip('remove')`.